# Getting String from array?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hey guy's im trying to load a string from an array(in this case a url) then download the file, but i get this error below:

```
Argument cannot be Nothing.
Parameter name: address
```

Here is my code:

```
    Dim urld As String

    urld = dls.GetValue(dlcount)
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(urld, "images/image-" + dlcount.ToString + ".png")
    Form1.o.Text = Form1.o.Text + urld + vbNewLine
```

dls is the array.

I thought i did everything right but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to say for sure, but it looks like `urld` is `Nothing` when you call the `DownloadFile` method. This would be caused by the call to `dls.GetValue(dlcount)` returning `Nothing`.

So it's likely that there's *either* a problem with the `GetValue` method itself, *or* the value of `dlcount` that you're passing to it is invalid in some way.

Comment: Ok, did some debugging and that is the case, how would i go about retrieving a string at a certain index in the array?

Comment: @Duncan: Presumably just with `urld = dls(dlcount)`.

Comment: @Duncan: And there's definitely a valid string at that index of the array?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was my code for adding to the array. was using dls(count) = STRING HERE instead of dls.setValue(Value, index)

Comment: perhaps you have to take the starting index of 0 in account: and take dls(dlcount-1)?